# Function is not defined - passing value and opening modal

Tags: php, html, function

When clicking a button, I would like to call a function and pass a recipe ID. The function will then open a modal window but currently receiving an error - myFunction is not defined.

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction(<?php echo $recipeID ?>)" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Open Modal</button>

<script>
```

```
function myFunction($recipeID){
    echo $recipeID;
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        });
    </script>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling an PHP function in javascript. PHP is executed first on server side and after that javascript on client side.

Answer (score 0):

`myFunction` is defined on server-side, that is, this `function` is on the server. You try to call it via Javascript in the browser, but the `function` is not defined there. You will need to change the definition of your `button` to

```
<button type="button" onclick="$('#myModal').modal('show');" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Open Modal</button>
```